# Where can I find the step by step new user's install guide to windows 10 gui?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, installation

I can't seem to get this to work no matter what.

And I know my way around the OS, security and networking.

Just where to look (don't tell me to read the source, please).

Comment: Please be specific about the action you're taking that is having an unexpected result, because otherwise it's extremely difficult for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to understand your frame of reference.  The short answer is:

1. Go to getmonero.org and download the latest zip file.
2. Extract the zip on your computer wherever you want to.
3. Double-click `monero-wallet-gui`.*

   - You technically have the choice of downloading the blockchain or using a remote node. The default/recommended way is to "run your own node," meaning download the blockchain.
   - Also, I'm passing over the steps to restore or create a new wallet.  There are instructions in many places, and it's generally straightforward anyway.

There does happen to be a bug with one or more of the v0.13 GUIs where `monerod` does not automatically start up on its own.  In that case, your wallet would have nothing to connect to.  If you are in the settings and have 'local node' selected in the 'Node' tab, and you go to the 'Log' tab and type `status` and it tells you it cannot connect to 127.0.0.1, then you'll need to manually start `monerod`.  So, in the same place you extracted everything else will be `monerod`, so double-click it.  Then you should be able to type `status` in the GUI to confirm that it is downloading the blockchain.

Once the blockchain is downloaded (you can compare to moneroblocks.info or xmrchain.net, among others), you'll be able to use the wallet.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the monero gui guide from erciccione [here](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-GUI-guide/blob/master/monero-GUI-guide.md).
It does contain anything you should know from setting up the gui wallet to transactions.